# Refreshing Single Cell in Base Adapter in android

Tags: android

I want to get the function that only refreshes one cell of GridView
Currently I am using baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() which refreshes whole grid , and I have to do this even I have only cell having different data
How can I do it

Comment: can't you just call the adapter's `getView` method directly?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but this do not update data on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't refresh single cell, but to achieve this effect we can get position of first cell displayed in the screen (not the first cell of the grid), then simply save that position ,refresh whole grid and preview from that saved position

```
            int prevcurr = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            Adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
            gridview.setSelection(prevcurr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before apply your changment in the cell.
After use this code (for me is about the gridview)

```
    adapterForImage.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridview.setAdapter(adapterForImage);
```

Comment: CustomAdapter adapterForImage;

It is a class for to adapt (in my case) a layout N times in the gridview.